# Marking equal sides in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to put mark for showing AD=CE=BF, AC=DE and CB=EF. I searched for this in site but couldn't manage to do it. Here is my code;

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1.2pt]
  \draw (0,0) rectangle (5,-5);
  \draw (2,0)--(2,-5);
  \fill[pattern = north east lines,pattern color=green] (0,0) rectangle (2,-5);
   \fill[pattern = north east lines,pattern color=red] (2,0) rectangle (5,-5);
     \node at (0,0) [circle,fill,inner sep=1pt]{};
     \node at (5,0) [circle,fill,inner sep=1pt]{};
     \node at (2,0) [circle,fill,inner sep=1pt]{};
     \node at (0,-5) [circle,fill,inner sep=1pt]{};
     \node at (2,-5) [circle,fill,inner sep=1pt]{};
     \node at (5,-5) [circle,fill,inner sep=1pt]{};
        \node[above] at (0,0){A};
        \node[above] at (5,0){B};
        \node[above] at (2,0){C};
        \node[below] at (0,-5){D};
        \node[below] at (2,-5){E};
        \node[below] at (5,-5){F};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

thanks in advance for any help and guidance.

Comment: Could you please specify what this mark should look like?

Comment: it can be anything like || , |, S or O etc.

Comment: OK, did you have a look at the `tkz-euclide` package?

Comment: @marmot My apologies, I saw this comments after posting my answer. I could delete it if you're preparing one already

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3pt]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1.2pt]
  \draw (0,0) rectangle (5,-5);
  \draw (2,0)--(2,-5);
  \fill[pattern = north east lines,pattern color=green] (0,0) rectangle (2,-5);
   \fill[pattern = north east lines,pattern color=red] (2,0) rectangle (5,-5);
     \node (A) at (0,0) [circle,fill,inner sep=1pt]{};
     \node (B) at (5,0) [circle,fill,inner sep=1pt]{};
     \node (C) at (2,0) [circle,fill,inner sep=1pt]{};
     \node (D) at (0,-5) [circle,fill,inner sep=1pt]{};
     \node (E) at (2,-5) [circle,fill,inner sep=1pt]{};
     \node (F) at (5,-5) [circle,fill,inner sep=1pt]{};
     \node[above] at (A) {A};
     \node[above] at (B) {B};
     \node[above] at (C) {C};
     \node[below] at (D) {D};
     \node[below] at (E) {E};
     \node[below] at (F) {F};

     \tkzMarkSegment[color=red,pos=.5,mark=|](A,D)
     \tkzMarkSegment[color=red,pos=.5,mark=|](C,E)
     \tkzMarkSegment[color=red,pos=.5,mark=|](B,F)

     \tkzMarkSegment[color=orange,pos=.5,mark=||](A,C)
     \tkzMarkSegment[color=orange,pos=.5,mark=||](D,E)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks and no worries. I was working on an alternative answer since tkz-euclide does to my best knowledge not yet support marks with more than 2 lines. (+1)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now i can mark with " | " , "||" and "|||"... , but is there an option like horizontal type of "S" ? Marking only  with " | " , "||" and "|||" can be misleading.

Comment: @AlperErdem You can use " oo ", " z ", " s ", " ||| "

Comment: @caverac thanks for all your help, it worked. Have a good day :)

Answer (score 2):

Just in case you want marks with more than 2 lines. (I also cleaned up your code a bit, you do not need to create extra nodes for labelling existing nodes.)

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1.2pt]
  \draw (0,0) rectangle (5,-5);
  \draw[decoration = {markings,mark=at position 0.5 with 
  {\draw(0,-3pt)--(0,3pt);}},postaction={decorate}] (0,0)--(0,-5);
  \draw[decoration = {markings,mark=at position 0.5 with 
  {\draw(0,-3pt)--(0,3pt);}},postaction={decorate}] (2,0)--(2,-5);
  \draw[decoration = {markings,mark=at position 0.5 with 
  {\draw(0,-3pt)--(0,3pt);}},postaction={decorate}] (5,0)--(5,-5);
  \draw[decoration = {markings,mark=at position 0.5 with 
  {\draw(-2pt,-3pt)--(-2pt,3pt);\draw(2pt,-3pt)--(2pt,3pt);}},postaction={decorate}] 
  (0,0)--(2,0);
  \draw[decoration = {markings,mark=at position 0.5 with 
  {\draw(-2pt,-3pt)--(-2pt,3pt);\draw(2pt,-3pt)--(2pt,3pt);}},postaction={decorate}] 
  (0,-5)--(2,-5);
  \draw[decoration = {markings,mark=at position 0.5 with 
  {\draw(-4pt,-3pt)--(-4pt,3pt);\draw(0,-3pt)--(0,3pt);\draw(4pt,-3pt)--(4pt,3pt);}},postaction={decorate}] 
  (2,0)--(5,0);
  \draw[decoration = {markings,mark=at position 0.5 with 
  {\draw(-4pt,-3pt)--(-4pt,3pt);\draw(0,-3pt)--(0,3pt);\draw(4pt,-3pt)--(4pt,3pt);}},postaction={decorate}] 
  (2,-5)--(5,-5);  
  \fill[pattern = north east lines,pattern color=green] (0,0) rectangle (2,-5);
   \fill[pattern = north east lines,pattern color=red] (2,0) rectangle (5,-5);
     \node[label=above:A] at (0,0) [circle,fill,inner sep=1pt]{};
     \node[label=above:B] at (5,0) [circle,fill,inner sep=1pt]{};
     \node[label=above:C] at (2,0) [circle,fill,inner sep=1pt]{};
     \node[label=below:D] at (0,-5) [circle,fill,inner sep=1pt]{};
     \node[label=below:E] at (2,-5) [circle,fill,inner sep=1pt]{};
     \node[label=below:F] at (5,-5) [circle,fill,inner sep=1pt]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]